# Jagged Array sorting in java

Tags: java, sorting

Recently I faced a question in an interview and I was unable to make logic for this question. I have an array like

`[ 1,'a',45,'h',56,'d',2,'t',6,'p' ]` . How to sort this array ? Output should be in this manner..

```
intArray = [1,2,6,45,56] 
charArray= ['a','d','h','p','t']
```

If anybody knows its logic please comment. It would be a great help.

Thanks !

Comment: is it `Array` or `ArrayList` ?

Comment: How original array is stored in an array?

Comment: @Satya, NamanGala, does that matter? It's a question about sorting heterogeneous elements. I don't think the specifics of the underlying data structure matter that much. In all interviews I've done pseudo code has been fine.

Comment: OP, I guess you could split the array into an `intArray` and a `charArray` first, and then sort those two arrays separately. Or, you could create a comparator that primarily sorts on element type and secondarily on value. Then sort the whole thing and split it in two.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be separate the integers and then sort-

```
Object[] objects = new Object[]{ 1,'a',45,'h',56,'d',2,'t',6,'p' };

List integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List characters = new ArrayList<Character>();

// Check and store integers and characters
// Doesn't validate and assumes you either have integers or characters
for(Object o : objects){
    if(o instanceof Integer){
        integers.add(o);                
    } else {                
        characters.add(o);
    }       
}

//Sort them separately
Collections.sort(integers);
Collections.sort(characters);

System.out.println(integers);
System.out.println(characters);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all separate the integers and character into different
   arrays by checking its instance type.
2. If characters are stored in ASCII form (in java it is stored in ASCII form) you can directly sort them using any of the sorting algorithm, treating each value as integer only.
3. Similarly you can apply any sorting algorithm on integer array.

Answer (score 0):

The following code produces desired result:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

final Map<Class<?>, Set<Object>> result = Stream.of(array) //
        .collect(//
                groupingBy(x -> x.getClass(), //
                        mapping(x -> x, toCollection(TreeSet::new))));
```

to view results:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result.get(Integer.class).toArray()));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result.get(Character.class).toArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the implementation of it. I have used two for loops so that we can easily find out the length of the two new subarrays instead of initializing it with the base array;s length.
I have tried not to use any in-built methods except Arrays.sort(). You can also write your own code to sort these two sub arrays.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[] array = { 1, 'a', 2, 'f', 5, 'b', 3 };

    int intLoc = 0;
    int charLoc = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] instanceof Integer) {
            intLoc++;
        } else {
            charLoc++;
        }
    }
    int intArray[] = new int[intLoc];
    char charArray[] = new char[charLoc];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] instanceof Integer) {
            --intLoc;
            intArray[intLoc] = (int) array[i];
        } else {
            --charLoc;
            charArray[charLoc] = (char) array[i];
        }
    }

    Arrays.sort(intArray);
    Arrays.sort(charArray);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(charArray));

}
```